# String to date issues

Tags: java, string, date

I'm running into a problem where I can change my String to a Date but I can't retrieve the data because it's in a try/catch block :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");

try {
  Date date = formatter.parse(input);
  System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any ideas on how I can retrieve the data?

Additional info: The project is to have someone input his day and month of birth so the program can go check on an Excel sheet what his astrological sign is. Do I need to convert the input to a date or am I banging my head against a wall?

Comment: Move this declaration before try block : Date date = formatter.parse(input);

Comment: @sunrise76 Move that entire line out of the try block would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Sorry. My intention is declaration of Date ( Declaration => only variable definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your date before the `try/catch`:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
Date date = null;
try {
    date = formatter.parse(input);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `date` outside the try-catch-block and fill it inside the block. Afterwards the data will be in the variable, or not, depending on whether and at what point the try failed. This means you'll have to be prepared that it isn't filled and check for null etc.

```
Date date = null;
try {
  date = formatter.parse(input);
  System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
if (date != null) { doSomething(date); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `date` outside the `try` block as in the other answers; however, since you almost certainly need a valid value to proceed anyway, you should probably just include the code for processing it in the `try` block as well. I.e.:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");

try {
    Date date = formatter.parse(input);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
    // do whatever you need with date here...
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```